# Facing Network Error for some second in ecs fargate deployment

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs, aws-fargate

I am facing network error glitch while accessing service deployed on ECS Fargate,The network erorr comes for fraction of sencond and resolved automatically,while Prod environmnet which is operating smoothly within the same VPC (running on ECS EC2).I have deployed Fargate services in private VPC and accessing it through ALB. This suggests the issue is specific to the QA environment and Fargate configuration. Key Observations: No load or traffic on the application during error occurrences. Error disappears quickly and is absent from service logs. Network mode and security groups of QA and Prod environments seem identical.

I have increased fargate TASK configuration from 0.25 vCPU, and 0.5 RAM, to 0.5 vcpu and 1 GB RAM.